# Iframe vertical scrollbar appearing right after submit button is pushed

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a contact form displayed in an iframe in an overlay div that I have adjusted to fit the div within the guidelines of the div dimensions. There are no scrollbars showing when the div first appears. Then I fill out the form, hit send, and there is a moment right after I hit send that the vertical scrollbar appears, obviously while the form is sending, and then the scrollbar disappears again after I get the confirmation screen.

[image: Contact Form Example of Scrollbar appearing]

Now I don't really know where to start, except that I believe my css is good. I have two css files attached to my contact.php.  I also have a process_form.php and three javascript files (two of which are jquery references). I don't want to paste all of them here because of all the code. Like I said, I have went through the css up and down, but I am not as experience with js or php to see if it is something in the code there. If anyone can point me in the right direction as to where to look, that would be great.  If you want me to post a certain section of code, I will.  But like I said, I don't want to just post random code here.  In the image above, the top screenshot is before I hit submit, the second image down is seconds after hitting send, and then the last image is my confirmation.  The scrollbar is only vertical for a second.  And I have already applied the following class to my iframe, which does not help:

```
.restrict{
width: 700px;
height: 380px;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

What is peculiar about that also, is that I had to adjust the width of all the elements in my contact form perfectly to get it to fit into my display div because the vertical scrollbar kept showing anyways with the above class.  So I am not sure why the overflow property wasn't working before I adjusted the width in my css of my elements, but I could not get rid of that vertical scrollbar until I got my form to fit inside my display div.

Any suggestion as to how I can just get the vertical scrollbar not to show up at all would be great if it is too difficult to examine my code to find the problem in the first place.

Comment: Do you have a live link where we can see this issue?

Comment: Use this 'overflow: hidden;' instead of this 'overflow-y: hidden;'.

Comment: @Gimmy I agree with `overflow: hidden;` CharlWillia6 what was the result for this suggestion, can you share with us?

Comment: This happens as far as I can see during the fadeout. Can you include a non-minified version of jQuery? That would make debugging much easier. Also a dumb question: Why are you using an iframe here in the first place?

Comment: Oh, and a more current jQuery version maybe a good idea, too.

Comment: I am using a iframe here because the contact form script that I have has much different styling that my own, and since I already have styling on some of my input elements already, it was just easier to set my contact.php into an iframe instead of changing all my styles. But since I cannot find a solution to this, I may need to rethink the iframe thing.  I have now updated my jquery link to include 1.10.1, the uncompressed version.

Comment: I also noticed that updating my jquery library link broke a lot of my styles.  So I might still need to revert back and find another solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using css you can use html to hide scroll bars. Like this-

```
<iframe scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I hope this helps.